# Java Swing: Get window that is in front or in focus

Tags: java, swing

I have an application with multiple windows. Is it possible to get the windows in the front or that is in focus without keeping track?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work me, I get the following error can not make static reference to the non static method of getFocusOwner()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate this information using the following:

```
Window windows[] = Window.getWindows();
for (Window w) {
  if (w.isFocused()) {
     ...
  }
  else if(w.isActive()) {
     ...
  }
}
```